# WP All Import and custom field which has relationship

Tags: match, relationship, custom-post-type, custom-fields, wpallimport

I'm working with WP All Import plugin to import several new records to my custom post created with Pods - Custom Content Types and Fields plugin.

I can easily import fields that have no relationships, but with the 1 field which has relationship I have troubles.

I have excel file(which I want to import) with names of companies, but the problem is that Pods - Custom Content Types and Fields plugin is storing ID of company in DB and not its name. So when I'm importing this xls file I'm able to choose the ID of company from drop-sown list and not company name.

How can I import company names from xls to this custom field which is storing IDs of companies.

I've already tried something like this:

```
MATCH ( post_title :  {globalcompanyname[1]} )
```

but it's not working.